# Adding tiles to map from multiple sources

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am working on a map for which I have multiple tiles sources that I want to be able to activate and deactivate using a menu on the side. Each tile set works independently when overlayed as an image map type, however I apparently can't show more than one of these at a time.

In any case, is it possible to display tiles from multiple tile url's? If not, then should I make some super overlay of tiles from all of my sources, and try to control which get loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can load and show as much tiles as you want to.

I can't tell you what went wrong in your approach without any code,
so I made an example: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/NNJRn/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/NNJRn/)

(Code for Overlay-Creation taken from the [google-demo](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple.html))

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will be quite useful. I've used the same site to put up what I'm working on, but I can't seem to get it to load the API. What I've got is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Azrael001/vMeTu/1/

Comment: Instead of "onload" choose "no wrap(body)" from the fiddle-options. You'll get an error "undefined P31D8_6MapType" then, what should it be?

Comment: P31D8_6MapType should have been TopoMapType. With that fixed, it loads up all of the tiles for that zoom level. Because the tiles aren't online, and take forever to reproduce the 404 errors pointing to http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/######.png should be taken as successful calls.

Comment: Disregard everything after the first sentence, I took to long editing. Because the tiles aren't online, and I don't know where I can stick a sample folder of them to load, getting 404's for them is fine. It shouldn't be trying to load them without the correct checkbox being checked though. It looks like it's looking for them even though the folder paths haven't been added in, which should have been obvious to me while writing it.